# SQL If record exist update, if not insert

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL query like so:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Reservations 
                                    SET ReservationsID = (SELECT PersonID FROM People WHERE Name = @Name) WHERE 
                                    SchedulePersonID = (SELECT SchedulePersonID FROM SchedulePerson WHERE (ScheduleID = (SELECT ScheduleID FROM Schedule WHERE Store_No = @StoreNo)) 
                                    AND LibraryTaskID = @Task)");
```

What I am trying to do is, if the record does not exists, insert it. if the record does not exist I would like to insert the  ReservationsID and SchedulePersonID into that table. I have seen some examples online, but I do not understand them. Please help.

Comment: You code doesn't make any sense to me. Not sure why you have so many select statements in there. You really should move this to a stored procedure and get the data out of your application. Once this is a stored procedure it is pretty simple, you update the row you want to update, then if no rows are updated you insert.

Comment: Why not have an if statement testing if the record exists then update/insert based on the result of that if statement? and as @Sean Lange stated, its best to put this into a SP

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Reservations 
SET ReservationsID = (SELECT PersonID FROM People WHERE Name = @Name) 
WHERE SchedulePersonID = (SELECT SchedulePersonID FROM SchedulePerson   
WHERE (ScheduleID = 
 (SELECT ScheduleID FROM Schedule WHERE Store_No = @StoreNo)) 
                                    AND LibraryTaskID = @Task)");
```

Isn't going to do what you want, but the biggest thing is `Insert != Update`. That is, you must do one or the other as the syntax is different.

```
Insert Table(Fields...) Values(FieldValues...)
Update Table set Fields=Values,... Conditions
```

PseudoCode

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQueryWithFieldsYouWantToUpdateOrInsertInOneTable,connection);
SqlAdapter adapter = new SqlAdapter(command)
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
DataSet dataset = adapter.Fill(table,"tableName")
DataTable datatable = dataset.tables["tableName"];
if(datatable.Rows.Count == 1) {
  DataRow row = datatable.rows[0];
  row.Field["fieldName"] = fieldValue;
  adapter.update(datatable);
}
else if (datatable.Rows.Count == 0) {
  DataRow row = datatable.NewRow();
  // row.Field["fieldName"] = fieldValue;
  datatable.Rows.Add(row);
  adapter.update(datatable);
}
else {
  multiple rows match conditions...
}
```